# How to insert the loop variable into output dataframe as a new column

Tags: r

I have a list of variables(`a,b,c)` from df1 which i want to pass into a API call. When we pass each variable it gives out data which may have any number of rows depending on data.
Below is the code I am using:

```
df$list ### has variables (a,b,c)
output_df<- data.frame()

for(k in 1:length(df$list)) {
  
  res1z = GET(paste0("url1",df$list[[k]],"&StartDate=02-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))
  dataz = fromJSON(rawToChar(res1z$content))
  dataz <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(rawToChar(res1z$content)))
  # dataz$emp_code<- df$list[[k]]
  
  
  output_df <- rbind(output_dfz1,dataz)
```

**df$list** is the following dataframe

```
SNo          List          
1            a         
2            b        
3            c
```

The expected output i am trying to get is adding that variable column to the api output.When I try to insert it just inserts the variable a or b for just the first record.

```
SNo          OP2          OP3         OP4         OP5     Variable
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     a
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     a
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     a
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     a
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     a
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     b
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     b
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     b
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     b
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     b
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over `1:length(df$list)`, use `names(df$list)`, and add the name on each loop:

```
output_df<- data.frame()
for(nm in names(df$list)) {
  res1z = GET(paste0("url1",df$list[[nm]],"&StartDate=02-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))
  dataz = fromJSON(rawToChar(res1z$content))
  dataz <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(rawToChar(res1z$content)))
  dataz$Variable <- nm
  output_df <- rbind(output_dfz1,dataz)
}
```

Or, using `lapply()` and `dplyr::bind_rows()`, using the `.id` argument:

```
output_df <- lapply(df$list, \(x) {
    res1z = GET(paste0("url1",x,"&StartDate=02-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))
    dataz = fromJSON(rawToChar(res1z$content))
    as.data.frame(fromJSON(rawToChar(res1z$content)))
  }) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "Variable")
```

Comment: Thank you .. the first solution throws the following error. I think this happens when the API returns no data

Comment: also the second one just adds s.no to the field variable but I want to add the list value to that field variable

Comment: "throws the following error" - what is the error? "just adds s.no to the field variable" - what is the "field variable"?

Comment: Please add a sample of `df$list` to your original post. It would also be better if you could provide a [mre] that doesn't require calling an API. Otherwise, if it's a public API, provide the URL. Otherwise it's harder to provide an answer that will work for your specific data and problem.

Comment: Error while trying the first option : ```Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Variable", value = 57L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0